# Interface builder not loading after Xcode crash

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, interface-builder

**What happened:**

1. I was editing a View with lots of Stack Views in it, which was
   causing Xcode to behave very slowly.
2. In one of these edits, I changed the spacing between stacks and Xcode stopped responding.
3. I forced quit.

**The problem**

The projects and all its files are opening just fine, but when I go to Main.storyboard, the loading icon never stops spinning. It doesn't load.

**What I've tried so far to fix it**

- I restarted the computer.
- I cleaned the project and built again.
- I've opened other Xcode projects and the IB opens just fine, looks like the problem is only with the project I was working on when it stopped responding.

Any tips on how I could solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Additional info:
Xcode Version 9.2

Comment: Is your project in source control or do you have time machine backups? You might have corrupted your storyboard file, it might be useful to roll it back to an earlier point in time.

Comment: Always work with some sort of version control. And whenever you reach a reasonable point in your project, commit your work. Be prepared for the worst at all the time. I'd suggest you to take a look at git, unless you are already using it. If not using it, I strongly suggest you to use it.

Comment: Thank you, Luk and Alp. That’s definitely the lesson learned. I was using git, but haven’t committed in a long time (still getting acquainted with it). I’m rebuilding the project from the beginning, using a branching model and committing every significant step of the way. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: I'm having crashes too and guess what? I'm using stack views.  Hope this has been reported to Apple.